# Does a LDAP Connection which successfully "connects" but fails to "bind", requires to be disconnected?

Tags: java, ldapconnection

I am creating a `LDAP Connection` using ldap `connect` function. Then I authenticate the user with username and password using `bind`.

I want to ask if the `bind` fails then, does the `Connection` is terminated or I need to disconnect it explicitly using `disconnect`?

P.S.: I am using Java LDAP.

UPDATE:

I am using `connect` and `bind` functions from class `LDAPConnection` in `com.novell.ldap.*`.

Comment: Which Java LDAP API? I'm aware of at least three or four.

Comment: @EJP : I am using `com.novell.ldap.*`. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned any library I am assuming you are using `javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext`.

When using `LdapContext`, you usually connect/bind with `new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);`

If that's the case, and the `bind` fails, you won't even get the object of `LdapContext` as the code will throw exception. So you don't need to (if fact you can't) call `ldapContext.close()`

If there is some library that is being used, you may need to refer that library's documentation.

**Update**:

Looking at the [javadoc](http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/jldap/jldapenu/api/com/novell/ldap/LDAPConnection.html#connect%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) of the library that you are using, it seems that the connection is not closed when the bind fails as it tries to make an anonymous connection first. I feel you should explicitly close the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using this library and I have updated my question mentioning proper API.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a object you can close or disconnect, you must close or disconnect it.